# Cyclic Groups and the order of an element.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a cylic group if two elements have the same order does that mean that they are the same element.

ie.e let $G = <g>$ and let $a,b \in G$ such that $a^k = b^k = 1_G$ then is it necessarily true that $a=b$.

Comment: No. For each divisor $d$ of $|G|$, there will be $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: Think about $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. Then $8[2] = [0] = 8[3]$, where the operation is addition mod $4$, and taking powers really means repeated addition.

Comment: Or you can think in $\mathbb{Z}/ 3\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly $1\ne 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not.  In fact, it usually is not true.  First a really simple case.  Suppose, $a^3 = 1$ then $a^6 = (a^3)^2 = (a^2)^3 = 1$.  But $a^2$ does not equal $a$.
Next example, the Klein 4 group, $a^2 = e, b^2 = e, (ab)^2 = e,$ but $a$ does not equal $b$ which does not equal $(ab).$